# Activity gets destroy while ActivityCompat.requestPermissions

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, usbserial, android-mediaprojection

I downloaded the "usb-serial-for-android" sample application from this link.

https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

Home screen displays the usb device and while clicking on it the moving to second screen to read the data which usb sends. In that screen I have added displaying camera and screen recording using media projection and SurfaceView.

**Problem**: When the app opens for the first time, while moving to second screen im calling **ActivityCompat.requestPermissions** for run time permission. During permission pop up second activity gets disappeared and permission dialog appears on the first screen.

I googled and tried various possibilities but can't able to solve the issue. Don't know how to avoid disappearing second screen. Created separate app for camera and screen recording which works fine. I got blocked this issue past two days.

Thanks in advance.

The log while I am trying to start screen recording

```
2019-05-07 15:42:35.251 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/ViewRootImpl@2c5f603[SerialConsoleActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
2019-05-07 15:42:35.372 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/ViewRootImpl@2c5f603[SerialConsoleActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
2019-05-07 15:42:35.377 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples I/MediaRecorderJNI: setAudioSource(1)
2019-05-07 15:42:35.381 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples I/MediaRecorderJNI: setVideoSource(2)
2019-05-07 15:42:35.384 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples I/MediaRecorderJNI: setVideoSize(1024, 768)
2019-05-07 15:42:35.385 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples I/MediaRecorderJNI: setVideoEncoder(2)
2019-05-07 15:42:35.385 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples I/MediaRecorderJNI: setAudioEncoder(1)
2019-05-07 15:42:35.386 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples I/MediaRecorderJNI: setParameter()
2019-05-07 15:42:35.386 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples I/MediaRecorderJNI: setVideoFrameRate(30)
2019-05-07 15:42:35.388 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples I/MediaRecorderJNI: setParameter()
2019-05-07 15:42:35.394 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples I/MediaRecorderJNI: setOutputFile
2019-05-07 15:42:35.395 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples I/MediaRecorderJNI: prepare
2019-05-07 15:42:35.611 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/ViewRootImpl@2c5f603[SerialConsoleActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
2019-05-07 15:42:35.617 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples I/SerialConsoleActivity: Stopping io manager ..
2019-05-07 15:42:35.617 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples I/SerialInputOutputManager: Stop requested
2019-05-07 15:42:35.617 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/UsbDeviceConnectionJNI: close
2019-05-07 15:42:35.627 9546-11208/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples I/SerialInputOutputManager: Stopping mState=STOPPING
2019-05-07 15:42:35.627 9546-11208/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples I/SerialInputOutputManager: Stopped.
2019-05-07 15:42:35.685 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/ViewRootImpl@d1c48c5[DeviceListActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1024,768] newFrame=[0,0][1024,768] result=0x7 surface={isValid=true -2009718784} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
2019-05-07 15:42:35.686 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/ViewRootImpl@d1c48c5[DeviceListActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true -2009718784} hwInitialized=true
2019-05-07 15:42:35.735 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/ViewRootImpl@d1c48c5[DeviceListActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
2019-05-07 15:42:35.736 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/ViewRootImpl@d1c48c5[DeviceListActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true -2009718784}
2019-05-07 15:42:35.739 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@7f4afc5 nm : com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples ic=null
2019-05-07 15:42:35.739 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2019-05-07 15:42:35.755 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=124
2019-05-07 15:42:35.755 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=110
2019-05-07 15:42:35.783 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/ViewRootImpl@d1c48c5[DeviceListActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1024,768] newFrame=[0,0][1024,768] result=0x1 surface={isValid=true -2009718784} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
2019-05-07 15:42:35.796 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/SurfaceView: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[682,531][1024,768] newFrame=[682,531][1024,768] result=0x5 surface={Surface(name=null)/@0xcea0dac isValid=false 0}
2019-05-07 15:42:36.179 9546-9574/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x88daca80 (InsetDrawable) with handle 0x8be7f0e0
2019-05-07 15:42:36.187 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/ViewRootImpl@2c5f603[SerialConsoleActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
2019-05-07 15:42:36.203 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/ViewRootImpl@2c5f603[SerialConsoleActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1024,768] newFrame=[0,0][1024,768] result=0x5 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
2019-05-07 15:42:36.205 9546-10879/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/DeviceListActivity: Refreshing device list ...
2019-05-07 15:42:36.275 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples I/SerialConsoleActivity: MediaProjection Stopped
2019-05-07 15:42:36.318 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/ViewRootImpl@2c5f603[SerialConsoleActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#4
2019-05-07 15:42:36.318 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/ViewRootImpl@2c5f603[SerialConsoleActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
2019-05-07 15:42:36.325 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=104
2019-05-07 15:42:37.221 9546-10879/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/DeviceListActivity: + com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.FtdiSerialDriver@d6127d: 1 port
2019-05-07 15:42:37.225 9546-9546/com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples D/DeviceListActivity: Done refreshing, 1 entries found.
```

Comment: Please show the related error logs so we know what's going on. If it disappears, it usually means there's an uncaught error in your program.

Comment: I'm not getting any error log also. That's the biggest issue which made me to got block.

Comment: have you added the permissions you are requesting dynamically in your manifest? the problem you are having occurs mostly due to this reason.